# A map from the absolutely convergent squences to the square summable sequences, is it compact? Is it open?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ \iota: \ell ( \Bbb N) \to \ell^2(\Bbb Z) $ be the inclusion map.

(a) Is $ \iota $ compact?

(b) Is $ \iota $ open?

I'm having a bit of trouble answering these questions even though I know a lot about the map itself.  It's clear that this is an inclusion, as all sequences that are absolutely convergent are also square summable.

For (b) The approach I was thinking of was  using the fact that $ \ell ( \Bbb N) \subset  \ell^2 ( \Bbb N) $ and trying to show this is and open subset.  I'm just not sure what exactly I'm looking at, is it a set of sequences whih converge, how would one show this is open?

For (a) I know the definition of a compact operator, briefly, $\iota$ is a compact operator between two spaces if $   \iota \overline B_1(0) $ is compact.  But when dealing with a set of sequence it's much easier to use the equivalent: X is compact is every sequence has a convergent sub sequence but I don't see exactly how to apply this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a) Let $e_k=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$, where the $1$ is the $k$-th position. $\{e_k\}_{k\ge1}$ is bounded in $\ell_1$, but $\{\iota(e_k)\}_{k\ge1}$ has no convergent subsequence in $\ell_2$.

b) $\iota(\ell_1)$ is not open in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Any neighborhood of $(0,0,\dots)$ in  $\ell^2$ contains a sequence of the form
$$(\dots,0,\epsilon,\frac\epsilon2,\dots,\frac\epsilon n,\dots)$$
that is not in $\iota(\ell_1)$.